# Check and clear filters with django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io) to filter a `ListView` and would like to display a "Clear all filters" link if any filters are applied.

Due to the generic nature of the filtering system I haven't yet found a straightforward way to achieve this.

The only thing I came up with so far is to return the regular queryset in the `get_queryset` method of the view if a "clear" flag is present in the request, however this doesn't actually clear the filters - it just returns all the data.

Does anyone have a solution/idea for this?

**Update: Solution**

After Jerin's comment I decided to solve this problem in 2 separate parts:

**has filter:**

I check if any of the fields I defined in my filter class are in the request. My solution looks a bit different as I'm using class based views so I abstracted it away in a mixin but if you're using simple views [like here](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/usage.html#the-view), you could just do:

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    has_filter = any(field in request.GET for field in 
set(f.get_fields()))

    return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {
        'filter': f,
        'has_filter': has_filter
    })
```

**clear all filters:**

A simple redirect to your list view:

```
{% if has_filter %}
  <a href="{%  url 'products' %}">{% trans 'Clear all filters' %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what about placing a `Clear all filters` button that will redirect to your default `ListView` (`/host/end/point/`) ?

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that initially but ended up ditching the idea because it didn't solve the `has_filters` problem. But I now solved that separately, so if you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the mixup version of the answer (combination of mine and [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682583/chris))
You could place a `Clear all filters` button and that will redirect to your default ListView (`/host/end/point/`).
But some `non-filter parameters` (such as `pagination` or something else) may occur in URL. So the better option is, check for any filter fields in URL and if so, display the filter clearing link
The opted solution is,

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    has_filter = any(field in request.GET for field in set(f.get_fields()))

    return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {
        'filter': f,
        'has_filter': has_filter
    })
```

and in template,

```
{% if has_filter %}
  <a href="{%  url 'products' %}">{% trans 'Clear all filters' %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Regarding `has_filter`, I would prefer `has_filter  = len(filter.qs._has_filters().__dict__['children']) > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a button and point to the base search field.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'App:FilterView' %}">Reset</a>
```

Comment: Mind that the `<a>` tag should be put outside the filter form.

Answer (score 2):

If your `FilterSet` instance is available on the template you can check for `filter.is_bound` like this:

```html
{% if filter.is_bound %}
<a href="{% url 'list_view_url' %}">Clear filters</a>
{% endif %}
```

If you are using the `FilterMixin` or the `FilterView`, your `FilterSet` instance will be available as `filter` to the template as above.

Answer (score 1):

I like this simple solution, however when I attempt to use it the current filter parameters are some how getting appended to the url even though it's the base url in the anchor.

So hovering over the button my link (determined using `{% url 'app:view' %}` shows 
`localhost/app/view` correctly

However when clicking the button the url in browser has the parameters appended
`localhost/app/view/?filter1=val1&filter2=val2` etc.

Is django caching something? Is browser (Chrome) caching? Can I force something in the anchor to not use them?

Answered my own, but for anyone else passing by:
I had the anchor on a button within a the filter form, although it was not a submit button moving it outside the form gave the desired result.