# Clear Filter with django-filter and django-tables2 (CBV)

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-tables2

Taken from another thread which didn't detail the 'Class Based View' example.

[Check and clear filters with django-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732359/check-and-clear-filters-with-django-filter)

What would the CBV of the following code look like:

```
def product_list(request):
f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
has_filter = any(field in request.GET for field in 
set(f.get_fields()))

return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {
    'filter': f,
    'has_filter': has_filter
})
```

I have tried numerous iterations added to my CBV code:

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from django_tables2.views import SingleTableMixin


class FilteredPersonListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
table_class = PersonTable
model = Person
template_name = 'template.html'

filterset_class = PersonFilter
```

But cannot get the table to render once included.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Dan